# Missing number in subfigure

Tags: subfloats, subfig

I used either one, same error. Could not check where is my error.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subfigure}



\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
   \centering
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
\caption{test1}
\end{subfigure}
% \hfil
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
\caption{test2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Testing}
 \label{fig:Features}
    \end{figure}
```

\end{document}

[image]

[image]

Comment: please post an example that produces this error, also it is more helpful to show the error as text in a code block rather than an image. You can use `example-image` as the image as it is available for tests but your example should be a complete docuemnt. subfig and subfigure do not have the same syntax so you need to say which you are using.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks. edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using the syntax of the `subcaption` package so

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subcaption}



\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
   \centering
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
\caption{test1}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
\caption{test2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Testing}
 \label{fig:Features}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. i was thinking i need to use `\usepackage{subfigure}` or `\usepackage{subfig}` because of `subfigure`

Comment: @aan if you read `texdoc subfig` (as I just did to check the syntax) you will find that no environment called `subfigure` is mentioned.

Comment: @aan unrelated but `[htp]` is better than `[h]` as a figure option

Comment: I get very confused with the `htp` and others. I almost give up using this. I just want my table placed after the text and not in following pages in next section

Comment: @aan using `[h]` makes going to the end of the document much more likely as it means not at top of a page, or at bottom of a page or on a page with just figures as you omit t b and p from the argument

Comment: Carlise, what is the best solution for this? I also saw someone use `!`

Comment: @aan what is the best solution depends on what the problem is. The fact that the figure moves is not a problem that is the _only_ thing a figure does, it marks the content as a float that can be moved to help with page breaking. `!` is useful in some special cases but as it means "ignore the user-set constraints and place this even if it breaks those constraints" then obviously it doesn't make sense to use it all the time, it's a special-case over-ride.